# How can I register custom error handler in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm developing a Laravel package, have a service provider with views and everything, but I need to have custom error messages. How can I register custom error handler in my service provider?

Answer (score 4):

You can register custom handler by binding it with Laravel's exception handler class on service provider.

### Create Custom Handler

First you have to create custom exception handler class.

```
<?php
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class CustomHandler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
}
```

### Register Your Handler

Now register the class on your `AppServiceProvider`

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Exceptions\CustomHandler;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * Do not forget to import them before using!
         */ 
        $this->app->bind(
            ExceptionHandler::class,
            CustomHandler::class
        );   
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

For more information check this blog http://blog.sarav.co/registering-custom-exception-handler-laravel-5/

Comment: I just tested it in Laravel 5.4 and it's not working :(, any one have a solution please

Comment: Not working? Can you explain? Did you register your custom handler in AppServiceProvider? It should work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I did a typo while specifying the namespace correctly. Now I have edited the answer. Also tested it. It is working now. :)

Comment: This will override the original exception handler.

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel 8.0 you can use the built-in renderable and reportable methods on the Handler class that is bound to the ExceptionHandler contract (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions).

So for example:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        /** @var ExceptionHandler $exceptionHandler */
        $exceptionHandler = resolve(ExceptionHandler::class);

        $exceptionHandler->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
            if ($request->wantsJson()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Endpoint not found'
                ], 404);
            }
        });
    }
}
```