# Laravel 6 change back to the old 5.8 exception screen

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I really don't like the new exception screen in laravel 6. Is there a way to switch it back to the one from 5.8?

Comment: The old way was using [whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) so you could probably just install that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops is the old error handler, try to install it and register a new handler, there is one example here: [How can I register custom error handler in laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698429/how-can-i-register-custom-error-handler-in-laravel-5)

Find instructions how to install and use whoops here https://github.com/filp/whoops

PS: just be careful, this handler should be executes only on development environment